# How to get value of Vuex getter inside of Vue local data object

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

Hey this seemed to be pretty simple, but I just can't figure out how to get my loggedInUser object to work outside the template. I read through a bunch of other answers and I know I have to do something to store the getter in a local data object.

I have a temporary 'id' object set up because that's what I ultimately want to set to loggedInUser.id in order to attach to my Axios request.

Here's the page I want to make changes on:

```
<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
// import vuex from 'vuex'


export default {
   data: () => ({
      results: "",
      id: "15",
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['loggedInUser'])
  },
  // var id = {{loggedInUser}};
  methods: {

      getData() {
          this.$axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/actors/', 
            {params: {user: this.id} }
            )
            .then(response => {this.results = response.data});
           

      }
  }
}
</script>
```

and here's my index.js for store:

```
export const getters = {
    isAuthenticated(state) {
        return state.auth.loggedIn
    },
    loggedInUser(state) {
        return state.auth.user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [`mapGetters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) helper simply maps store getters to local computed
> properties

This:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['loggedInUser'])
},
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
computed: {
  loggedInUser() {
    return this.$store.getters.loggedInUser
  },
},
```

---

Replace `this.id` with `this.loggedInUser.id` in your axios request, and get rid of the temporary `id` data property.

```
 getData() {
   this.$axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/actors/', {
       params: {
         user: this.loggedInUser.id
       }
     })
     .then(response => {
       this.results = response.data
     });
 }
```

We are assuming `getData` only gets called when the user is authenticated. If that's not the case, have in mind `this.loggedInUser` may be `null` or `undefined` and accessing `this.loggedInUser.id` will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks! that's super simple, I think my mistake was trying that but with an extra set of brackets.